# insert data into database using servlet and jsp in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp, servlets

I am trying to add or insert values into table of database using servlet and jsp and MySQL Workbench as database. These are the following details:

1.> **Register.java**

```
package register.com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
/**
* Servlet implementation class Register
*/
@WebServlet("/register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Register() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 
            //String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/newData";// newData is the database  
            //Connection connection;  
            Connection conn=null;
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String dbName="userlogindb";
            String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        //String dbUserName="root";
        //String dbPassword="root";

        try{  
          String Fname = request.getParameter("fname");  
          String Mname = request.getParameter("mname");  
          String Lname = request.getParameter("lname");  
          String Uname = request.getParameter("username");  
          String Emailid = request.getParameter("emailid");  
          String Mobno = request.getParameter("mobno");  
          String Address = request.getParameter("address");  
          String Password1 = request.getParameter("password1");  
          String Password2 = request.getParameter("password2");  

          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();  
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,"root", "root");
          PreparedStatement pst =(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("insert into 'userlogindb'.'registerutable'(fname,mname,lname,username,emailid,mobno,address,password1,password2) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");//try2 is the name of the table  

          pst.setString(1,Fname);  
          pst.setString(2,Mname);        
          pst.setString(3,Lname);
          pst.setString(4,Uname);
          pst.setString(5,Emailid);
          pst.setString(6,Mobno);
          pst.setString(7,Address);
          pst.setString(8,Password1);
          pst.setString(9,Password2);


          int i = pst.executeUpdate();
          conn.commit(); 
          String msg=" ";
          if(i!=0){  
            msg="Record has been inserted";
            pw.println("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");  


          }  
          else{  
            msg="failed to insert the data";
            pw.println("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");
           }  
          pst.close();
        }  
        catch (Exception e){  
          pw.println(e);  
        }  

}

}
```

2.> **index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="registrationform" action="register" method="post">
<p>
Enter your first name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Enter your middle name: <input type="text" name="mname"><br>
Enter your last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</p><br>
<p>
Enter username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
</p><br>
<p>
Enter email id: <input type="text" name="emailid"><br>
Enter mobile number: <input type="text" name="mobno"><br>
Enter address: <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="address"></textarea><br>
</p><br>
<p>
Enter the password: <input type="password" name="password1"><br>
Reenter the password: <input type="password" name="password2"><br>
</p><br>
<p>
<input type="submit">
</p><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

3.> **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>RegisterExample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description>Register Servlet</description>
<display-name>Register</display-name>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>register.com.Register</servlet-class>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

4.> *I have added mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and servlet-api-3.0.jar* is anything else needed to add it. I have created a connection to database in Data Source Explorer.

When I m compiling or debuging it shows no error. During runtime also there is no error.
When I fill in the form and submit it shows only blank screen :(
No output is displayed. :(
Also in the database values are not updated.

Please help me. I m getting hangover with this snippet.

Comment: is your mysql server running?

Comment: Use print() method instead of println() and close the pw.

Comment: yes mysql server is running Kazekage Gaara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `doPost()` method of servlet is called from the jsp form and remove `conn.commit`.

Comment: Yess Niks Tyagi Sir, you are correct program run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check value of `i` by putting logger or println(). and check with closing db conn at the end. Rest your code looks fine and it should work.

Comment: Gautam Savaliya I have added i to the print statement but it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Same problem fetch main problem in  `PreparedStatement` use simple statement then you successfully insert record same use below.

```
String  st2="insert into 
user(gender,name,address,telephone,fax,email,
     destination,sdate,edate,Participant,hcategory,
     Culture,Nature,People,Cities,Beaches,Festivals,username,password) 
values('"+gender+"','"+name+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+fax+"',
       '"+email+"','"+desti+"','"+sdate+"','"+edate+"','"+parti+"',
       '"+hotel+"','"+chk1+"','"+chk2+"','"+chk3+"','"+chk4+"',
       '"+chk5+"','"+chk6+"','"+user+"','"+password+"')";


int i=stm.executeUpdate(st2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP at line `<form>` tag,
try this code

```
<form name="registrationform" action="Register" method="post">
```

Comment: Including 4 spaces in front of your code sample causes the code to be shown in a code block. In the case of HTML tags if you do not include the tag is a code block it will not be visible and your answer may be deleted if it appears to have no code in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String user = request.getParameter("uname");
out.println(user); 
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
out.println(pass); 
Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rental","root","root" ) ;
out.println("hello");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "insert into login (user,pass) values('" + user + "','" + pass + "')";
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove conn.commit from Register.java

In your jsp change action to :`<form name="registrationform" action="Register" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by identifying which JDBC driver I intended to use. In my case, I was connecting to an Oracle database.  I placed the following statement, prior to creating the connection variable.

DriverManager.registerDriver( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());